# Bicep remediation task loop

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a loop in bicep to go through policyDefinitions in a initiative assignment and create a remediation task for each of them. I get multiple errors when running my code:
`can't be evaluated, property name must be a string.'"`

this is my bicep files:
policyDefinition.bicep

```
targetScope = 'managementGroup'
// added new parameter of type array and removed name, pattern and policyType
param policies array

// added loop inside the module iterating over the value provided for the policies parameter
resource policyDefinitionsName 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions@2021-06-01' existing = [for policy in policies: {
  name: policy.name
}]

// Create an output constructed in the format the format that Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions accepts for the policyDefinitions property
output policyDefinitions array = [for (policy, i) in policies: {
  policyDefinitionId: policyDefinitionsName[i].id
}]
```

policyRemediation.bicep

```
targetScope = 'managementGroup'

@description('The Policy Definitions that were applied')
param policyDefinitions array
@description('The Policy Assignment ID')
param policyAssignmentId string

resource remediateTask 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights/remediations@2021-10-01' = [for (definition, i) in policyDefinitions: {
  name: guid('Remediate-${definition.policyDefinitionId}')
  properties: {
    failureThreshold: {
      percentage: 1
    }
    resourceCount: 500
    policyAssignmentId: policyAssignmentId
    policyDefinitionReferenceId: definition[i].policyDefinitionId
    parallelDeployments: 10
    resourceDiscoveryMode: 'ExistingNonCompliant'
  }
}]
```

main.bicep

```
module initiatives './modules/policyInitiative.bicep' =  {
  name: initiativeName
  params: {
    initiativeName: initiativeName
    // passing in the output from the policy definition deployment as value to the policyDefinitions parameter
    policyDefinitions: policyDefinitionsName.outputs.policyDefinitions

  }
}

resource policyAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments@2021-06-01' = {
  name: 'test policyAssignment'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    description: 'testassign'
    displayName: 'test policyAssignment'
    policyDefinitionId: initiatives.outputs.initiativeId
  }
}

resource roleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: guid(policyAssignment.name,'1')
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
    principalId: policyAssignment.identity.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

module remediateTask 'modules/policyRemediation.bicep' = {
  name: 'remediate-task'
  params: {
    policyAssignmentId: policyAssignment.id
    policyDefinitions: policyDefinitionsName.outputs.policyDefinitions
  }
}
```

Any suggestions to what im doing wrong here?

```
module remediateTask 'modules/policyRemediation.bicep' = {
  name: 'remediate-task'
  params: {
    policyAssignmentId: policyAssignment.id
    policyDefinitions: policyDefinitionsName.outputs.policyDefinitions
  }
}
```

Expected remediation tasks to be made for each definition instead multiple errors with same error message `The language expression property '7' can't be evaluated, property name must be a string`

Answer (score 0):

While creating the remediation tasks in bicep file, there is no need to pass it as
`policyDefinitionReferenceId: definition[i].policyDefinitionId`. Because definition is a single object that represents the policy definitions rather than an array.

*I modified your code as below:*

```bash
resource remediateTask 'Microsoft.PolicyInsights/remediations@2021-10-01' = [for definition in (properties.policyDefinitionId): {
  name: guid('Remediate-${definition}')
  properties: {
    failureThreshold: {
      percentage: 1
    }
    resourceCount: 500
    policyAssignmentId: initiativeDefinitionPolicyAssignment.id
    policyDefinitionReferenceId: definition.policyDefinitionID
    parallelDeployments: 10
    resourceDiscoveryMode: 'ExistingNonCompliant'
  }
}]
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

*Note:* You are passing the `policyDefinitionsName.outputs.policyDefinitions` output to the initiatives module's `policyDefinitions` argument. However, because `policyDefinitionsName` is a resource rather than a module, it doesn't have an `outputs` property.

Modify it to

```bash
policyDefinitions: policyDefinition.outputs.policyDefinitions
```

in `main.bicep` file.

Refer [blog](https://dev.to/omiossec/bicep-and-azure-policy-manage-policy-and-initiative-assignment-5b7k) by @Olivier Miossec & [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.policyinsights/2019-07-01/remediations?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) for better understanding.